# firebase - save current authenticated user and current server timestamp when writing to realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying save current authenticated user and current server timestamp when writing to realtime database. not from client but from the server

here is an example to illustrate my thought

```
let comment = firebase.database().ref().child(`comments/${postId}`).push();
comment.set({comment: 'Hello World'});
```

what I want to be saved is :

```
comments : {
    "-L1CLZlQ9AAtAYyNanqM" : {
        comment : 'Hello World' ,
        time : 12512623463                // CURRENT FIREBASE SERVER TIME
        userId : "-M1CB342845tAYyNanqM"  // CURRENT AUTHENTICATED USER ID
    } ,
    ...
}
```

**time** and **userId** should be provided from server

cloud functions may solve the issue but I'm wondering if there is another way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can if i understood correctly, first get the uid

```
uid:string; // define globally

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    this.uid = user.uid;
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Now use `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to get the server time

```
let comment = firebase.database().ref().child(`comments/${postId}`).push();
comment.set({
    comment: 'Hello World',
    time:firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    userId:this.uid
    });
```

Comment: no , I don't want to set the time and userId from the client. but thank for your time

Comment: @Ali: The above code sets the server-side timestamp. That is the only way to set such a timestamp from the client.